# add screenshot for an iPhone app in Waiting for Review state

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, itunes-store

will it take longer time to get approved, if I add a screenshot for an app in 'Waiting for Review' state. I mean, does making any change make the queue all the way to the back again as if the app is submitted on that day?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wait for it to be approved and you will be able to change the screenshots as part of the metadata for your app (this won't require further approval from Apple).

Comment: Doing it while its waiting for review is fine. I do that all the time.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The only thing that would effect your review time would be developer rejecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

if your application is in **"Waiting For Review"** state then you can change the Screenshots.