# Can I change the application screenshots when the app is in pending for review stage?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

my app is in "Pending for Review" stage in the appstore. Can I replace the screenshots of the app with new one? If yes, will it have any impact?

Comment: @Ty_ wow, really? it's sorry to give a wrong message, I deleted it. thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

**YES**

Explanation of **"Waiting For Review"** from the Apple Docs

> You’ve submitted a new app or updated version and it’s been received
> by Apple, but Apple hasn’t started reviewing the app. While your app
> is waiting for review, you can:
>
> - Reject your binary to remove it from
>   the Apple review queue.
> - Edit certain app information.

See more explanation of you app's status [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)

Comment: I'd appreciate you accepting the answer if it was helpful. Thanks

Comment: But, the apple link says that you can reject binary and can edit some information. Does it include screenshots?

Comment: The answer is YES. and see this link, it should be helpful as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692573/add-screenshot-for-an-iphone-app-in-waiting-for-review-state

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

if your application is in **"Waiting For Review"** state then you can change the Screenshots.